# Connecting flight in Heathrow next day flight

Tags: lhr, connecting-flights

I will be traveling to Brazil from the Philippines. I have a separate ticket Cebu Philippines to Incheon South Korea, vice-versa. Also, Incheon to Sao Paulo, Brazil with a connecting flight in Heathrow, London. On first pass by March 31, I have same day travel some maybe 7 hours difference. However, on my return passing Heathrow again it will be on April 13 4pm in Terminal 3 and leave for Incheon at 12 pm next day in Terminal 5. As a Philippine passport holder, do I need a Visa if I will just stay inside Heathrow airport(Terminal 3) as I wait for my flight to Incheon the next day? Thanks.

Comment: The last I heard, Heathrow terminals close overnight, so at some point you may be forced to enter the UK, so don’t bank on staying airside overnight.

Comment: You can stay overnight at Heathrow but they herd everyone into one space in T3 and then wake everyone up around 4:45 am to send them to their departure terminals. Don't count on getting much sleep.